# How can i push recursive array in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

i have to develop a gant chart with infinite threads. How can I insert a sub-task inside a sub-task recursively?
Thanks in advance

```
<select class="border border-gray-300 rounded-lg" v-model="taskParent">
   <option value="" selected>Select parent</option>
   <option v-for="parent in taskParents" :key="parent.id" :value="parent">
       {{parent.name}}
   </option>
</select>


const taskParents = computed(() => {
        return tasks.reduce((curr, task) => {
            curr.push(task)
            task.children.forEach((child) => { //this foreach is the part to be changed
                curr.push(task)
                })
            return curr
         }, []);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get a flattened representation of the array

```
function flatten(item){
  const result = [item];
  item.children.forEach(child => {
     result.push(...flatten(child));
  });
  return result;
}
```

Then just write

`const taskParents = computed(() => { return flatten(task) }`